# WebControl not loading from c#

Tags: asp.net

I'm adding a WebControl (ascx) to a TabPane from c#, and it does not show up.
 i'm doing something like this:

```
    ...
        TabPage tab = new TabPage(e.Parameter);
        WebUserControl1 wc = new Views.WebUserControl1();
        tab.Controls.Add(wc);
        myASPxPageControl.TabPages.Add(tab);
        myASPxPageControl.ActiveTabIndex = myASPxPageControl.TabPages.Count - 1;`
    ...
```

but, if i add the same ascx directly in the main page in the asp code it does show up.

When adding from c# the component does not do the "loaded method", but when embedded in the asp it does load.

i've already tried another approach in the c# doing this:

```
var wc = (WebUserControl1)Page.LoadControl("~/Views/WebUserControl1.ascx");
```

but is the same thing, it does not show up, only show up in the asp code.

Any thought?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error while running this code?

Comment: Have you checked all the tabs? Does it show up in rendered HTML at all?

Comment: In which event are you executing the code?